# pymongo taking over 24 hours to loop through 200K records

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have two collections in a db `page` and `pagearchive` I am trying to clean up. I noticed that new documents were being created in the `pagearchive` instead of adding values to embedded documents as intended. So essentially what this script is doing is going through every document in `page` and then finding all copies of that document in `pagearchive` and moving data I want into a single document and deleted the extras.

The problem is there is only 200K documents in `pagearchive` and based on the count variable I am printing at the bottom, it's taking anywhere from 30min to 60+ min to iterate through 1000 records. This is extremely slow. The largest count in duplicate docs I have seen is 88. But for the most part when I query in `pageArchive` on `uu`, I see 1-2 duplicate documents.

mongodb is on a single instance 64 bit machine with 16GB of RAM. 
 The `uu` key that is being iterating on the `pageArchive` collection is a string. I made sure there was an index on that field `db.pagearchive.ensureIndex({uu:1})` I also did a `mongod --repair` for good measure.

My guess is the problem is with my sloppy python code (not very good at it) or perhaps something I am missing that is necessary for mongodb. Why is it going so slow or what can I do to speed it up dramatically?

I thought maybe because the `uu` field is a string it's causing a bottleneck, but that's the unique property in the document (or will be once I clean up this collection). On top of that, when I stop the process and restart it, it speeds up to about 1000 records a second. Until it starts finding duplicates again in the collection, then it goes dog slow again (deleting about 100 records every 10-20 minutes)

```
from pymongo import Connection
import datetime


def match_dates(old, new):
    if old['coll_at'].month == new['coll_at'].month and old['coll_at'].day == new['coll_at'].day and old['coll_at'].year == new['coll_at'].year:
        return False

    return new

connection = Connection('dashboard.dev')


db = connection['mydb']

pageArchive = db['pagearchive']
pages = db['page']

count = 0
for page in pages.find(timeout=False):

    archive_keep = None
    ids_to_delete = []
    for archive in pageArchive.find({"uu" : page['uu']}):

        if archive_keep == None:
            #this is the first record we found, so we will store data from duplicate records with this one; delete the rest
            archive_keep = archive
        else:
            for attr in archive_keep.keys():
                #make sure we are dealing with an embedded document field
                if isinstance(archive_keep[attr], basestring) or attr == 'updated_at':
                    continue
                else:
                    try:
                        if len(archive_keep[attr]) == 0:
                            continue
                    except TypeError:
                        continue
                    try:
                        #We've got our first embedded doc from a property to compare against
                        for obj in archive_keep[attr]:
                            if archive['_id'] not in ids_to_delete:
                                ids_to_delete.append(archive['_id'])
                            #loop through secondary archive doc (comparing against the archive keep)
                            for attr_old in archive.keys():
                                #make sure we are dealing with an embedded document field
                                if isinstance(archive[attr_old], basestring) or attr_old == 'updated_at':
                                    continue
                                else:
                                    try:
                                        #now we know we're dealing with a list, make sure it has data
                                        if len(archive[attr_old]) == 0:
                                            continue
                                    except TypeError:
                                        continue
                                    if attr == attr_old:
                                        #document prop. match; loop through embedded document array and make sure data wasn't collected on the same day
                                        for obj2 in archive[attr_old]:
                                            new_obj = match_dates(obj, obj2)
                                            if new_obj != False:
                                                archive_keep[attr].append(new_obj)
                    except TypeError, te:
                        'not iterable'
        pageArchive.update({
                            '_id':archive_keep['_id']}, 
                           {"$set": archive_keep}, 
                           upsert=False)
        for mongoId in ids_to_delete:
            pageArchive.remove({'_id':mongoId})
        count += 1
        if count % 100 == 0:
            print str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ' ### ' + str(count)
```

Comment: the first thing that catches the eye `ids_to_delete = []` and then `if archive['_id'] not in ids_to_delete`. Consider using `set`. Lookup in sets is O(1).

Comment: Another slowdown may came from `for page in pages.find()`. If your pages are big, and you are using only `uu` key, maybe limit results to `uu` key with `fields` argument?

Comment: You mean by just doing `from set import Set` and redefining `ids_to_delete = Set([])` ?

Comment: OK good call, I will try only returning the uu field from the first document loop and report back.

Comment: No, I mean [builtin set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). `ids_to_delete = set()`; `ids_to_delete.add(archive['_id'])`

Comment: `match_dates` returns False. I'd make it return `None` and change `if new_obj != False:` to `if new_obj is not None`. It will check reference, and will not call object `__ne__` or `__nonzero__`

Comment: OK I have made all the changes you suggested and started running it again. I am going to let it go like 10-20 minutes and see how much it has improved and report back. If you wanted to explain your comments in an actual answer (might help someone in the future who is shaky at python like me), I will be more than happy to accept after this test completes. I can already tell by looking at `top` that mongod is working a bit harder so I am guessing it's processing much faster.

Comment: I just got thrown this error, so my timeout must not be configured right: `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: cursor id '8869742604286774394' not valid at server`

Comment: `for page in pages.find({}, {'uu':1}, timeout=False):`

Comment: Strange. Maybe `for page in pages.find(fields=['uu'], timeout=False):`

Comment: And I don't see `db.pagearchive.ensure_index('uu')` in code? Indexes in mongo have little time to live. Are you calling it in begin of each script run?

Comment: No I wasn't. I thought I only had to do it once from the mongo shell?

Comment: No, default ttl for pymongo is 300 seconds. I think it's main problem.

Comment: Also, I tried this option too, `for page in pages.find(fields=['uu'], timeout=False):` and got another timeout

Comment: Is it works without `fields` parameter?

Comment: I was wrong about index live time, it's actual only for pymongo fast chek of index existence. But `ensure_index` before queries is still good practice.

Comment: No, it is still timing out no matter which timeout=False version I use. I may put it on both queries for good measure, and open another question if it still timesout. I will also add `ensure_index`. Where do you suggest adding it into the code?

Comment: I just put it at the beginning before the first loop `pages.ensure_index('uu')
pageArchive.ensure_index('uu')`

Comment: Yes, it's the right place. What about speed improvement, has all this changes helped?

Comment: It seems like it, but it's hard to tell because of the timeouts. It gets to this line that prints at the end, hangs for a while, then timeout. I may open a new question if it has another timeout even though I put timeout=False on both query loops.
`2012-02-11 11:37:48.230439 ### 20000`

Comment: But the timeout comes after at least 10-15 minutes of waiting for it to print the next line. Until I get the timeouts resolved, it will be hard to tell improvements. But it seems like it cut the time in half.

Comment: I think I have found another problem, but this is with the data...It looks like multiple instances of `uu` may be blank, causing the hangup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make following changes to code:

- in `match_dates` return `None` instead `False` and do `if new_obj is not None:` it will check reference, without calling object `__ne__` or `__nonzero__`.
- `for page in pages.find(timeout=False):` If only `uu` key is used and pages are big, `fields=['uu']` parameter to `find` should speedup queries.
- `archive_keep == None` to `archive_keep is None`
- `archive_keep[attr]` is called 4 times. It will be little faster to save `keep_obj = archive_keep[attr]` and then use `keep_obj`.
- change `ids_to_delete = []` to `ids_to_delete = set()`. Then `if archive['_id'] not in ids_to_delete:` will be O(1)

Comment: It is much much faster now. Between your suggestions and deleting the bad records, it's processing & 10K records a minute now. It would go even faster if I had it on more than one machine sharded right?

Comment: @Hallik, not sure about that. I think Python CPU usage in this script is big.